# Check if link has https:// in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I have tons of data in JSON format in my angular app,

```
[
  {"link": "https://stackoverflow.com"},
  {"link": "https://stackoverflow.com"},
  {"link": "id-aW783D"}, //This is a wrong data
  {"link": "https://stackoverflow.com"}
]
```

But as you can see in JSON, 3rd object has an invalid value (NOT A LINK),

Now I need to bind those links with `a` on it, but `{"link": "id-aW783D"}` goes invalid in `a` because it's not a valid URL.

I added this code to avoid invalid links, but with this code and heavy data, app takes lots of time to load.

```
for(i; i < $scope.data.length; i++){
 item = $scope.data[i];
 if (item.link.indexOf("https://")){
   item.ID = item.link;
 }
 else item.ID = '';
}
```

Now my Question is, is there any other way to do this, like with `ng-if` ?

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [
    {"link": "https://stackoverflow.com"},
    {"link": "https://stackoverflow.com"},
    {"link": "id-aW783D"},
    {"link": "https://stackoverflow.com"}
  ];
  var i = 0;
  for (i; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
    item = $scope.data[i];
    if (item.link.indexOf("https://")) {
      item.ID = item.link;
    } else item.ID = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="j in data track by $index">
    <li ng-if="j.ID">{{j.link}}</li>
    <li ng-if="!j.ID"><a href="{{j.link}}">{{j.link}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `filter`!

Answer (score 1):

Js is quite fast. Ng-if is much slower. As well as rendering html tags

I.e. running your "for" for 1 million objects:

```
var start = new Date();
for(i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
 item = {link: '123321https://'};
 if (item.link.indexOf("https://")){
   item.ID = item.link;
 }
 else item.ID = '';
}
console.log(new Date() - start)
```

Takes 139ms in my chrome.

I doupt my computer will survive page having 1kk links on page.

Actually what you need is virtual/infinite scroll.

Comment: Your above example is fast but not in my case, I have nested json data on large scale, maybe I need to add server side pagination, thanks for you response. :)

Comment: Point is that any js-function processing result will be much faster than rendering tags until you have some really heavy calculations. So thin point is rendering not JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `ng-show="j.ID.indexOf('https') == 0"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize for larger amounts of data, you don't want to offload that filter logic to the template. You could try different logic, such as

```
var data_to_render = $scope.data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.link.indexOf("https://") === 0;
})
```

That will return a new array, since mutation in javascript *can* be costly, and avoids assigning to that `item` variable X times.

Other than that, if you're just showing a list of data, you'll probably want to limit the number of elements shown as much as possible. Filtering through hundreds of thousands of items in an array isn't really an issue, it's *rendering* them all at once that will slow down most devices.